# How to setup custom "service" reboot for Apache?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

I'm trying to get the Apache script function to run like so:

```
 service httpd restart
```

Currently, I have to do it this way (much more long winded, and I forget it all the time :))

```
 /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

How do I go about configuring this? I've done some research on Google, but  I can't find anything (I expect its because I'm not sure of the correct terminology :)). Other stuff like nginx, solr, mysql, etc ... all have the "*service x action*" function, so I'm quite surprised it didn't come with Apache too

Thanks!

Comment: You don't say which version of Linux you are running, or how Apache was installed.  Both pieces of information wouldbe useful.

Comment: @neuro - thanks for the comment. If you look below, and answer has already been given. Just FYI, its Debian 8, with Apache2. I'm not sure how Apache was installed, as my friend did it for me (I guess with apt-get, but couldn't say for sure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`service` is largely just a wrapper around calls to `/etc/init.d/x` scripts. If `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart` works,

```
service apache2 restart
```

should also work.

Answer (score 1):

Recommended way of restarting apache is :

```
apachectl graceful
```

or

```
apachectl restart
```

also of course you can use

```
service apache2 restart
```